# Laravel upgrade 4.1.x & packages for 4.0.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Is it possible to use packages requiring `illuminate/support` for `4.0.x` in Laravel `4.1.x`??? Half of the packages in my project aren't usable if I upgrade Laravel. I'm not familiar enough with Composer and packages yet to understand a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't, Composer will throw errors at you as there are multiple versions of the same code being requested.